# Django: Display many-to-many fields in the change list

Tags: sql, django, django-admin, many-to-many, django-select-related

Django doesn't support displaying of related objects from a many-to-many relation in the changelist for a good reason. It would result in a lot of database hits.

But sometimes it is inevitable and necessary to e.g. display an object's categories, which have a many-to-many relation to the object, in the changelist. Given that case, does anybody have some experiences/snippets etc. to speed this up a little (thinking of caching, custom sql queries...)? (I am aware of the fact that I can make a method that calls `object.categories.all()`... But this can really be a pain in the ass...).

Comment: What if you returned a flat values_list with the display value of the related data, and cached that per instance in your parent model? Then wire up a signal to reset these cached values when the parent model is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to make a choice about `denormalization` in your model if you think that one more database hit *per row* in your changelist is unacceptable.

The question is how to store this ManyToMany relation ? Maybe you can go with a synced [`JSON` serialized object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/#serializing-data) in a `CharField` or a `TextField` to serialize the subset of fields you need (`pk` and `name` for instance).

But be careful with the side effects on performances when adding a potentially big column, the queryset's [defer method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#defer) is your friend.